# What are some Websphere Application Server "time-out definition" solutions?

Tags: spring, timeout, websphere, rad

My organization is using Websphere Application Server with RAD. My unit is developing Web Services that take data from a consumer, and often pass the data through other Web Services.

Currently, we have two ways of defining time-out's for data to be returned from called services:

- Using the Spring framework
- Websphere profile configuration

If we need to update the values using Spring we need to re-deploy our service. If we define them as JVM properties we need to do a JVM configuration change and 'restart/recycle/stop and start' the application.

My co-worker had it suggested to him that there may be some better solutions to this problem. I'm wondering if this is true, and if so what they are?

edit:
One option we might be considering is "Application Policy Sets". We'd like to know if this is a good alternative method:

- can we define Spring to leverage policy sets
- can we define multiple policy sets for an application when timeout values for different services called by our service are different?
- Does this console change take affect at run-time, or do we need to recycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use JAX-WS policy sets and bindings on WAS level, because it allows you to:

- define policy set for each web service separately
- in policy set define web service parameters, from HTTP transport parameters to WS-Security policies such as UsernameToken, digital signature and encryption
- web services remain unchanged, the code remains the same
- there is only one place where you change it: in WAS console, application is not changed

The only drawback here is that web services should be generated from RAD (you can use top-down or bottom-up approach).

Please see more details in this excellent [3-part DeveloperWorks tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/websphere/libraryview.jsp?search_by=Message-level+security+with+JAX-WS+on+WebSphere+Application+Server+V7)

Comment: Forgot to mention: I have used this successfully for web services, I used UsernameToken and HTTP Transport parameters to modify connect, send and receive timeouts.

Comment: Thanks, I've now figured how to use policy sets to attach to the service we are deploying. Is it possible to use them to also define the properties of endpoints we are calling within the service as defined with Spring?

Comment: Depends on properties. What particular are you referring to, that is defined with Spring and you want to define it with policy set?